# How to list running processes in listbox or a combobox

Tags: c#, listbox, system

I am trying to populate a listbox with a list of running processes, so my users can select the process they wish to monitor.

I have tried the following, along with lots of variations of it and I just can't get it to work.

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
}
```

It doesn't do anything, however, I have seen others saying it worked for them. 
Any ideas?

Comment: There are no problems with the posted code. Where are you calling this from? Are you resetting the Items somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running on a timer or thread?

OR Insert the code below into the button click event.

```
Process[] allProc = Process.GetProcesses(); 
  foreach (Process p in allProc)
                {
                       listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure this really qualifies as an answer, but here's what I'd suggest: doing some troubleshooting to figure out just which of several problems is happening.

First thing I'd do is something like this:

```
string fancyDebugString = "";
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    fancyDebugString += p.ProcessName + ",";
    //listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
}
MessageBox.Show(fancyDebugString);  // or whatever feedback mechanism you can hook into.
```

... this will cover a lot of different possible problems: the Process.GetProcesses() isn't enumerating, the process list is blank somehow, the code isn't being called at all for some reason, etc.

If that works, and displays a comma-separated process list?  Uncomment out the listBox adding - see if the list box addition is screwing up the foreach somehow, and verifying that listBox1 has the items afterwards.